# clarification needed for constraint layouts

Tags: android, android-studio, androidx

I'm a bit lost with google and android dev documentation, and I can't really pinpoint what's the key difference  with `android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout` and `androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout`. Android Studio seems to give you the latter by default, but most texts on the subject seem to follow the former.

Comment: They're the same component, `androidx` is just the newest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, they represent the same thing. The main difference is that `androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout` represents the AndroidX version.

**What is AndroidX?**

[AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx) is an open-source project which was recently released by the Android team and the purpose is to replace all the original support library APIs.

Invariably, `androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout` is the newer/better version of `android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout` and this should be your preference.

To learn about migrating your existing project to AndroidX, [check this out](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate).

I hope this helps. Merry coding!

Answer (score 1):

> So it's not only for ConstraintLayout!

- But `AndroidX` is a major improvement to the original Android Support Library.
- Like the Support Library, AndroidX ships separately from the Android OS and provides backwards-compatibility across Android releases.[Here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx?gclid=CjwKCAjw7uPqBRBlEiwAYDsr18GbjPzkhH8VcaL1dHzdGmD28PQNm3oJ7iJwHYRJqc8B8Hx0rbpDzxoCV2oQAvD_BwE)
- Design support library requires `andriodX` migration too! You should consider using androidX for your future projects!
- [Here](https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started/) For design library to be used with `AndroidX` version add :
  **implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:version'**
- Migrate your project to `androidX` in Android Studio by going to: `Refactor-> Migrate to AndroidX` to migrate your project and there you can backup your project if some problem occurs migrating project.
- After that your dependendencies will have androidX packages automatically.